# How to run a function by clicking an option in a drop down select tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a drop down select tag like so :

```
<select id="thisDropDown" onChange="doSomething()">
        <option></option>
        <option>classif</option>
        <option>status</option>     
</select>
```

Notice I'm using the `onChange();`

What I need is the ability to re-click an option in my drop down so it runs the function again (as I can change other drop downs which affect the outcome of running this function).

I have tried `onselect()` and `onclick()` but none seem to work. Do I have to write a bit of script ? I have been looking online but can't seem to find something that will work.

Thanks in advance, sorry if something similar has been asked before

Comment: What you're trying to do is not clear. Do you mean that you want to run the `doSomething()` function again, even though the `change` event is not raised?

Comment: yes. I dont want to use onChange. I wish to use something like an onClick so that when i select the same option again (rather than changing it) it runs the function again. hope that helps

Comment: So if a user changes one of the other drop downs, they need to re-select the same value from this drop down to refresh some other value? That sounds more like a design issue.

Comment: @panther Chrome doesn't support any event bound to OPTION element

Comment: @panther that can not be done, `<option>` doesn't support events

Comment: well i didnt think of it like that @artm you are right. I am going about this the wrong way. sorry about that guys :)

Comment: @thisOneGuy It sounds like when one of the other selects change, you need to reset this select or display a "click here to refresh the other value" message.

Comment: yeah thats what i was thinking. a refresh button to rerun the function :) thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can achieve this but with minor tweaks which are required based on the browser

JSFiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/0kxe6br7/2/

```
var dom = "select#thisDropDown";
var is_firefox = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('firefox') > -1;
if(is_firefox){
dom+=" option";
}

$(dom).on("click",function(event) {
  console.log($(event.currentTarget).val());
});
```

Comment: very nice but this runs when i click the drop down too :/ i only want it to run when i click on an option in the drop down ...

Comment: The browser and its version you checked it in?

Comment: stupid me looked at it in chrome when obviously its firefox. How come you have done it so it's browser dependent ?

Comment: For chrome  its enough if we bind click event to the select box, but this does not work for firefox as it fires the event twice, so if its firefox we bind the click event to the option tag.

Answer (score 1):

Hej,

This can be done with jquery

```
$('#thisDropDown').on('mouseup', function() {

    alert('select option');
});
```

Comment: wouldn't you have to change the value of the drop down ? not just click it ?